# Upgrade webapp Grails 2 to Grails 3 : cannot see index.html anymore

Tags: angularjs, grails-3.1

I just updated my Grails 2 webapp project (Grails back end and Angular as front-end) to Grails 3.

I moved all the web-app folder from my grails2 project to src/main/webapp (tried also in src/main/resources) folder.

Now running bootRun -->http://localhost:8080/ up and running

Trying to access http://localhost:8080/index.html gets an error...

What I meant is that I cannot access to my HTML files. I get an error : "This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback." because I commented the error redirection in URLMappings. However, I do not understand why with Grails 3 my index.html is not accessible anymore while it worked ith Grails2 with the same configuration of URLMappings.

Surely missing something but have no clue what ?

Many thanks.

Comment: "gets an error..."  *What error?*

Comment: Please describe the error.

Comment: What I meant is that I cannot access the index.html. I get the following error because I commented the error redirection on URLMappings:Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Feb 02 21:31:36 CET 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available